# Camera sometimes stores unreadable .MOV instead of .JPG

Tags: storage, data-corruption, kodak

A recent development with my Kodak Z981 camera - i.e., I took 19 pictures. The first 4 and the last 3 were normal, 2 to 3 MB JPEG photos. The 12 pictures in between came out as 8-12 kB .MOV files which cannot be viewed. This has happened both of the last two times I used that camera.

I did not change any camera setting during the sessions. Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Open the ".mov" files in a text editor. See if there are any hints there amongst whatever is displayed.

Comment: What program did you use to view them? Can you view them on the camera?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

A .MOV file is a movie video. You select video mode with the rotary Mode switch on top of your camera, which must have been accidently moved. See your Extended User Manual page 9 about it:   http://resources.kodak.com/support/pdf/en/manuals/urg01118/Z981_xUG_GLB_en.pdf

.MOV is called a QuickTime file, which is an Apple format, but it is reasonably  compatible, for example your Kodak camera makes .MOV video files.  There are video converters that can convert them to other video formats.

I think you can play .MOV files in Windows Media Player.  Some sources say you need to add a codex before Media Player can play .MOV, but here, Microsoft says Media Player 12 can play them:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316992/file-types-supported-by-windows-media-player

Here is another list of programs that should open and play MOV: https://fileinfo.com/extension/mov
(and there are also others, I use a Cyberlink PowerDirector video editor or the VLC player)

Comment: 1) MOV is a container, so whether it is playable or not depends entirely on its content. (That said: such an old camera will probably use MPEG2 or MPEG4, so it should work with any recent player.) 2) 8-12 kB do not suffice to hold anything else than metadata - even one frame would be larger than that (usually).l

Comment: @flolilolilo [Apparently](https://www.techspot.com/products/cameras/kodak-easyshare-z981.28746/) H.264

Comment: @mattdm Thanks, though I did not find the reference in that link, but in [the manual](https://resources.kodak.com/support/pdf/en/manuals/urg01118/Z981_xUG_GLB_en.pdf#page=64)... I did a simple test - Opened AfterEffects, made an animation of 1 frame (just a square), exported it as 720p30 h.264 QT without Audio -> 1.22 MiB. Considering that AAC would be on board, too, there is no way that there is anything else than container data in this .MOV.